# tcl ping message every 30 seconds

Tags: sockets, tcl

I am following the echo service example on practical programming with tcl and tk, and I have some questions (in tcl) about implementing some additional things based on that code.

I am trying to transmit to all clients a message every 30 seconds. I am using "every" procedure defined in the wiki http://wiki.tcl.tk/9299 the part saying "To limit the number of repetitions, use return:[...]". Once the user leaves the server (via closing the socket), the every function still runs and I get error messages. How can I make a check to see if the socket is still on and if not I would stop sending messages?

Comment: show what you have so far

Comment: tomorrow, I don't have the files here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `every` script is extremely simple-minded, as it provides no easy mechanism for cancelling the repetition. However, you're using a version that it is quite straight-forward to actually handle terminating things nicely with. You've just got to catch the error (from the closed channel) and respond by `return`ing, which stops the `after` from being used.

```
proc every {ms body} {
    eval $body
    after $ms [info level 0]
}
every 30000 {
    if {[catch {
        puts $::channel "Hi there!"
    }]} return
}
```

It's probably better to do this with a helper procedure and a callback *technically* generated with `list`, which makes things touch on some of the more advanced features of Tcl:

```
proc every {ms body} {
    eval $body
    after $ms [info level 0]
}
proc sendThePing {channel} {
    if {[catch {
        puts $channel "Hi there!"
    }]} {
        # Make the _caller_ (every) return!
        return -level 2 done
    }
}

every 30000 [list sendThePing $theChannel]
```

This is better at handling multiple connections, more complex argument passing, etc.

Comment: Thanks. This is partially what I thought, it reminds me a lot of the callback usage in node.